# AngularJS Resource error callback being called with a promise

Tags: angularjs, resources

I've been writing a service in AngularJS to save some data and, if it fails, alert the user. However, after I create my resource and call $save:

```
myResource.$save(function(success) {
  console.log(success);
}, function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

I expect the error callback's argument to be an object with data, status, headers, etc., but all I get is an object with a "then" function. I tried to mock it up in JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/RichardBender/KeS7r/1/

However, this example works as I originally expected. I yanked this JSFiddle example and put it in my project and it has the same problem I originally described, despite that as far as I can tell everything else is equal. Does anyone have any idea why this might be? My project was created with Yeoman/Bower/Grunt but I can't see why those things would make a difference here.

Thanks,
Richard

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem. The error was in my HTTP interceptor, where upon an error code, I was accidentally returning $q.reject(promise) rather than $q.reject(response).

The bugged version:

```
.factory('httpInterceptor', function($q) {
    return function(promise) {
        return promise.then(
            // On success, just forward the response along.
            function(response) {
                return response;
            },
            function(response) {
                // ... where I process the error
                return $q.reject(promise);
            }
        );
    };
```

The fixed version:

```
.factory('httpInterceptor', function($q) {
    return function(promise) {
        return promise.then(
            // On success, just forward the response along.
            function(response) {
                return response;
            },
            function(response) {
                // ... where I process the error
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        );
    };
```

-Richard